# Scala: what is the interest in using Iterators?

Tags: scala, iterator

I have used `Iterators` after have worked with Regexes in Scala but I don't really understand the interest.
I know that it has a state and if I call the next() method on it, it will output a different result every time, but I don't see anything I can do with it and that is not possible with an `Iterable`.

And it doesn't seem to work as Akka Streams (for example) since the following example directly prints all the numbers (without waiting one second as I would expect it):

```
lazy val a = Iterator({Thread.sleep(1000); 1}, {Thread.sleep(1000); 2}, {Thread.sleep(1000); 3}) 
while(a.hasNext){ println(a.next()) }
```

So what is the purpose of using `Iterators`?

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking here. What are you expecting as output and what do you get? "I know that it has a state and if I call the next() method on it, it won't output a different result every time" is completely wrong. Iterators in general WILL return a different result on every call to `next`. "it not possible with an Iterable." - what is not possible?  So you seem very confused about what Iterators are. Please edit your question and see if you can make it clearer what you are asking.

Comment: An amazing question indeed! :)

Comment: @The Archetypal Paul : I want to understand the purpose of using Iterators. I'm not confused at all about it, but I have to admit that my question was (sorry for my english). I meant "it will" instead of "it won't". I have edited my question.

Comment: How are the current answers doing at answering your question?

Comment: The response of Dima is perfect and is what I suspected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps, the most useful property of iterators is that they are lazy.
Consider something like this:

```
   (1 to 10000)
     .map { x => x * x }
     .map { _.toString }
     .find { _ == "4" }
```

This snippet will square 10000 numbers, then generate 10000 strings, and then return the second one.
This on the other hand:

```
   (1 to 10000)
     .iterator
     .map { x => x * x }
     .map { _.toString }
     .find { _ == "4" }
```

... only computes two squares, and generates two strings.

Iterators are also often useful when you need to wrap around some poorly designed (java?) objects in order to be able to handle them in functional style:

```
val rs: ResultSet = jdbcQuery.executeQuery()
new Iterator { 
   def next = rs
   def hasNext = rs.next
}.map { rs =>
   fetchData(rs)
}
```

Streams are similar to iterators - they are also lazy, and also useful for wrapping:

```
Stream.continually(rs).takeWhile { _.next }.map(fetchData)
```

The main difference though is that streams remember the data that gets materialized, so that you can traverse them more than once. This is convenient, but may be costly if the original amount of data is very large, especially, if it gets filtered down to much smaller size:

```
Source
  .fromFile("huge_file.txt")
  .getLines 
  .filter(_ == "")
  .toList
```

This only uses, roughly (ignoring buffering, object overhead, and other implementation specific details), the amount of memory, necessary to keep one line in memory, plus however many empty lines there are in the file.

This on the other hand:

```
val reader = new FileReader("huge_file.txt")
Stream
  .continually(reader.readLine)
  .takeWhile(_ != null)
  .filter(_ == "")
  .toList
```

... will end up with the *entire content* of the `huge_file.txt` in memory.

Finally, if I understand the intent of your example correctly, here is how you could do it with iterators:

```
val iterator = Seq(1,2,3).iterator.map { n => Thread.sleep(1000); n }
iterator.foreach(println)
// Or while(iterator.hasNext) { println(iterator.next) } as you had it.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a good explanation of what iterator is http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_43.html

> An iterator is not a collection, but rather a way to access the
>   elements of a collection one by one. The two basic operations on an
>   iterator it are next and hasNext. A call to it.next() will return the
>   next element of the iterator and advance the state of the iterator.
>   Calling next again on the same iterator will then yield the element
>   one beyond the one returned previously. If there are no more elements
>   to return, a call to next will throw a NoSuchElementException.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should understand what is wrong with your example:

> lazy val a = Iterator({Thread.sleep(1); 1}, {Thread.sleep(1); 2},
>   {Thread.sleep(2); 3})  while(a.hasNext){ println(a.next()) }

if you look at the apply method of `Iterator`, you'll see there are no calls by name,so all `Thread.sleep` are calling at the same time when `apply` method calls. Also `Thread.sleep` takes parameter of time to sleep in milliseconds, so if you want to `sleep` your thread on one second you should pass `Thread.sleep(1000)`.
The companion object has additional methods which allow you do the next:

```
val a = Iterator.iterate(1)(x => {Thread.sleep(1000); x+1})
```

`Iterator` is very useful when you need to work with large data. Also you can implement your own:

```
val it = new Iterator[Int] {
  var i = -1
  def hasNext = true
  def next(): Int = { i += 1; i }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't see anything I can do with it and that is not possible with an Iterable

In fact, what most collection can do can also be done with Array, but we don't do that because it's much less convenient

So same reason apply to iterator, if you want to model a mutable state, then iterator makes more sense.

For example, Random is implemented in a way resemble to iterator because it's use case fit more naturally in iterator, rather than iterable.